# Django: How to do an override of fields based on it's value in an aggregation query (join on multiple columns)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have been looking for a while on different corners of the internet and the Django Project documentation without success so here my question:

As background I'm synchronizing the models with an external API so I would prefer not to have to change the model structure.

I have the following Models (just left the relevant fields for brevity):

- TimeEntry:

  ```py
  class TimeEntry(models.Model):
       id = CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
       duration_decimal = DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='dec duration')
       start = DateTimeField()
       project = ForeignKey(Project, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
       user = ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  ```
- Membership

  ```py
  class Membership(models.Model):
      user = ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
      project = ForeignKey(Project, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
      hourly_rate = ForeignKey(HourlyRate, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
      active = BooleanField(default=True)
  ```
- User

  ```py
  class User(models.Model):
      hourly_rate = DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
  ```
- HourlyRate

  ```py
  class HourlyRate(models.Model):
      amount = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default_currency='USD')
  ```

The hourly rate can be set at the user level and it can be overridden at the membership level, so I'm trying to create a Django-ORM query to get the value of the overridden hourly rate or the user hourly in case the value at the membership level is not defined and multiply it by the decimal duration and then aggregate everything per month to generate a reporting of hours consumed per month and it's monetary value.

Here the query I have currently that is working for the hourly rate at the user level:

- User Level Query

  ```py
  TimeEntry.objects.filter(project_id='xxxxxx')
  .annotate(year=ExtractYear('start'), month=ExtractMonth('start'))\
  .values('year', 'month')\
  .annotate(sum=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('user__hourly_rate')*F('duration_decimal')), DecimalField()), hours_sum=Sum('duration_decimal'), count=Count('id'))\
  .values('year', 'month', 'count', 'sum').order_by('-year', '-month')
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  +----------------------------------------------+
  |                    Results                   |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  | No | year | month | sum  | hours_sum | count |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  | 1  | 2020 |     1 | 1000 |        95 |    15 |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  | 2  | 2019 |    12 |  990 |        87 |     9 |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  | 3  | 2019 |    11 | 1250 |       113 |    21 |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  |    | ...  |       |      |           |       |
  +----+------+-------+------+-----------+-------+
  ```

This is my attempt to get the overridden values from the Membership Model

- Membership Level Query

  ```py
  TimeEntry.objects.filter(project_id='xxxxxx')
  .annotate(year=ExtractYear('start'), month=ExtractMonth('start'))\
  .values('year', 'month')\
  .annotate(sum=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('project__membership__hourly_rate__amount')*F('duration_decimal')), DecimalField()), count=Count('id'))\
  .order_by('-year', '-month').values('year', 'month', 'count', 'sum')
  ```

And here the generate SQL for this query:

- Membership Level generate SQL

  ```sql
  SELECT EXTRACT('year' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich')  AS "year",
    EXTRACT('month' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich') AS "month",
    SUM(("hourlyrate"."amount" * "timeentry"."duration_decimal")) AS "sum",
    COUNT("timeentry"."id")                                                AS "count"
  FROM "timeentry"
      INNER JOIN "project" ON ("timeentry"."project_id" = "project"."id")
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "membership" ON ("project"."id" = "clockify_membership"."project_id")
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "hourlyrate" ON ("membership"."hourly_rate_id" = "hourlyrate"."id")
  WHERE "timeentry"."project_id" = 'xxxxxx'
  GROUP BY EXTRACT ('year' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich'), EXTRACT ('month' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich')
  ORDER BY "year" DESC, "month" DESC
  ```

The problem with the generated SQL is that the first two JOINs are concatenated and not consolidated in one (that result in too many lines), here is the SQL that is giving the correct result:

- Membership Level generate SQL [corrected]

  ```sql
  SELECT EXTRACT('year' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich')  AS "year",
    EXTRACT('month' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich') AS "month",
    SUM(("hourlyrate"."amount" * "timeentry"."duration_decimal")) AS "sum",
    COUNT("timeentry"."id")                                                AS "count"
  FROM "timeentry"
      -- START> Here is the JOIN over two columns consolidating the two previous separated JOINs
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "membership" ON ("timeentry"."user_id" = "membership"."user_id" AND "membership"."project_id" = "timeentry"."project_id")
      -- <END
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "hourlyrate" ON ("membership"."hourly_rate_id" = "hourlyrate"."id")
  WHERE "timeentry"."project_id" = 'xxxxxx'
  GROUP BY EXTRACT ('year' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich'), EXTRACT ('month' FROM "timeentry"."start" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich')
  ORDER BY "year" DESC, "month" DESC
  ```

I think I can come up with an alternative solution using a SubQuery but then I don't know how to handle the override in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a `ForeignObject` on your `TimeEntry` model that points to the `Membership` one.

```py
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignObject


class TimeEntry(models.Model):
    ...
    project = ForeignKey(Project, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    user = ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    membership = ForeignObject(
        Membership,
        from_fields=('project', 'user'), 
        to_fields=('project', 'user')
    )
```

With this relationship defined your queryset will be able to use `Coalesce('membership__hourly_rate', 'membership__user__hourly_rate')`.